# wait for AsyncTask to finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In the OnCreate method, I have invoked 3 AsyncTask which basically fills data for the 3 Spinners. What I need is that I should have the Login button disabled till all 3 tasks finish. How can I achieve that ?

```
            new SpinnerDataFetcher("GetFreeDrivers1",(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_1)).execute();

            new SpinnerDataFetcher("GetFreeDrivers2",(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_2)).execute();

            new SpinnerDataFetcher("GetFreeDrivers3",(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner_3)).execute();
```

Comment: you shouldn't use AsyncTask like that , if you're trying to load some data try using AsyncTaskLoader instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increment a number that corresponds on how many `AsyncTask` are done.

```
        int s = 0;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            new SpinnerDataFetcher(){
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(....) {
                   super.onPostExecute(...);
                   s++;
                   check();
                }

            }.execute(); 

            new SpinnerDataFetcher(){
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(....) {
                   super.onPostExecute(...);
                   s++;
                   check();
                }

            }.execute(); 

            new SpinnerDataFetcher(){
               @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(....) {
                   super.onPostExecute(...);
                   s++;
                   check();
                }

            }.execute(); 

        }

        public void check(){
          if(s >=3){
             s= 0;
            // enable button here
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to Disable `Button`  before calling `new Spinner1DateFetcher` and call `Second` from `Spinner1DateFetcher` method `onPostExecute` and same as `Third Spinner` method and in `Third Spinner` `onPostExecute` set `Button` to `Enable`..

For **Disable Button** use

```
Button.setEnabled(false);
```

and For **Enable Button** use

```
   Button.setEnabled(true);
```

**Edit :**

for the parameter check you have to add `Constuctor` and check the condition like below way.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public MyAsyncTask(boolean showLoading) {
        super();
        // do stuff
    }

    // doInBackground() et al.
}
```

Comment: Your solution is awesome but the thing is that each of the AsyncTasks has different parameters. Please see my edited question.

Comment: Your answer suggests recursive call to the execute() function. But the argument is different for the 3 calls. How will I handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your AsyncTask instance with a reference to the Activity/Fragment that creates it.  Then signal back in onPostExecute when its done

e.g.

```
 class Spinner1DataFetcher extends AsyncTask<...> {
       public Spinner1DataFetch(YourActivityOrFragment activity) {
            _activity = activity;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(...) {
           _activity.spinner_1_is_done();
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways how you can achieve this.

The straightforward way to implement this is create a counter which will trigger UI update.

```
final InterfaceTrigger trigger = new InterfaceTrigger();

new AsyncTask<>() {
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        trigger.finishJob();
        if (trigger.isTimeToUpdateUi()) {
           // TODO update your UI
        }
    }
    };

public class InterfaceTrigger {
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 3;
    private int counter;

    public synchronized void finishJob() {
        counter++;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isTimeToUpdateUi() {
        return counter == THRESHOLD;
    }
}
```

Another way is to use `CyclicBarier` and `ExcutorService` mechanism.